# Python match regex pattern line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm working with this code that need to match the regex pattern line-by-line?

Is there anyway to put all the regex output into a list? I do have a draft code but I haven't figured it out. Though still trying to search for solution.

```
teststr = """router#sh ip bgp        
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, x best-external
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 6.120.0.0/18     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 6.120.0.0/17     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 13.44.61.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i
*> 13.44.62.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i"""

data = []
for line in teststr:
    if line !='':
        word = re.search('> \d............', line)
        data.append(str(word))
        print (data)
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to search for all the networks and save inside a list.

```
re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})/\d+',teststr)
```

Answer (score 1):

list.txt:

```
router#sh ip bgp        
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, x best-external
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 6.120.0.0/18     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 6.120.0.0/17     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 13.44.61.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i
*> 13.44.62.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]


# network list to save the ip's
netList = []

for line in content:
    if line.startswith("*>"):
        netList.append(line.split(" ")[1])


print(netList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['6.120.0.0/18', '6.120.0.0/17', '13.44.61.0/24', '13.44.62.0/24']
```

Comment: Thanks @user5173426

Answer (score 0):

```
data = []
for line in teststr.split('\n'):
    if line !='':
        word = re.search('> \d............', line)
        data.append(str(word))
        print (data)
```

Comment: This would require more content to explain why this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @abdullah.cu